# SharePoint 2013 - Display full breadcrumbs

Tags: sub-site, breadcrumb

When displaying a document list and browse through it's folders breadcrumbs are shown at the top as displayed in the below image:

[image]

Is it possible to display the full breadcrumbs i.e. 1 -> 2 -> 3 instead of 2 -> 3 only?

Can this be done to a sub site only instead of the whole farm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to customize the Master page or Page layout to show full breadcrumb. You can apply the Master page or Page Layout to particular sub site only.

Here is my code in my project for your reference. I added the SiteMapPath control to the Master HTML file as below:

```
<!--MS:<asp:SiteMapPath id="ContentMap" SiteMapProviders="SPSiteMapProvider,SPContentMapProvider" RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="true" SkipLinkText="" NodeStyle-CssClass="ms-sitemapdirectional" runat="server">-->
<!--ME:</asp:SiteMapPath>-->
```

Then hide the original one.

Also I found a similar reference in old discussion:
[Custom breadcrumb?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/24180/custom-breadcrumb)